# Custom action fails to install MySQL

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, deployment, custom-action

I have made a VS2010 project which installs MySQL by calling MySQLInstallerConsole.exe with necessary arguments. This works perfectly however, when I try to run this project's exe as a custom action it executes the exe but MySQL is not installed.

I checked the log file for MySQL exe and it had the following error:

Error 50: *Package Name* State change request failed.

What does this really mean, any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a couple of things that have something to do with this:

1. I believe the MySQL installer is an MSI file according to this:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer

You cannot install an MSI from a custom action of a Visual Studio setup because recursive calls to MSI installs are not allowed.

2. In a Everyone install custom actions run with the SYSTEM account, and installs are not often expecting this if they want to install files in user-profile folders because the SYSTEM account doesn't have any.

You need to bootstrap this somehow, and I think people are often using the WiX Burn bootstrapper for that. You define the ProductCode, name etc of the product and define how to install it.

Comment: Yes, MySQL installer is a MSI file. I made a bootstrap off it and extracted the MySQLInstallerConsole.exe file. This MySQLInstallerConsole.exe has to be executed with some arguments which I tested successfully as a seperate VS2010 project.

The problem is when I try to include VS2010 project exe as a custom action. It fails, I tried calling it as impersonate(user) and no-impersonate, all runs the MySQLInstallerConsole but fails to install anything.

Comment: Well you can't run an MSI-based install from a custom action in an VS setup project, period. Bootstrapping means installing it BEFORE you install your MSI. It's failing because as far as I know the console program is still running the MSI install, right?

Comment: Let me clarify, MySQL MSI extracts a manifest (This has to run as boostrap).The manifest that has been extracted contains MySQLInstallerConsole.exe which can be called in a MSI and this exe installs MySQL.

Now I don't have a problem with making the bootstrapper (already done and tested) but running exe in custom action. 

Running exe as VS2010 works perfectly. When I try to run it as custom action it runs alright even progress can be seen(though it is fast) however, in the end nothing is installed.